# Reversing the given string without using reverse function

Tags: c#, string

I want to reverse the given string without using string functions in c#.

Ex:I have "Welcome to the world" I want reverse like this:"world the to welcome"

Comment: Is this an interview question or assignment..

Comment: Split by whitespace and reverse.

Comment: Note that probably what you'll get is "world the to **W**elcome" :-)

Comment: Please show your effort so far. Do-my-homework-for-free-questions are unwelcome, especially such trivial ones.

Comment: without using Reverse..

Comment: Well, you *could* make fire by rubbing sticks together, but why would you want to do that when you have a dry backpack with various sets of matches, lighters and flamethrowers with you at all time?

Comment: You should have put homework in the title

Comment: @PaulZahra No, he should not.  He's welcome to say that it's homework in the body of the question if it's true and he feels like saying so.  Such information doesn't belong in the title at all, and isn't required at all, even if it is homework.

Comment: @Servy it's debatable and since he hasn't put it in the text and the HomeWork tag is deprecated putting it in the title would have been great. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @PaulZahra A title should naturally describe the problem.  You shouldn't be putting tags or random keywords in the title.  Where in that link is it saying you should be putting "homework" in the title of the question?

Comment: The link proves that it is debatable, some say it should be marked as homework, others say a question is a question.

Answer (score 2):

By using `Regex`es :-)

```
var str = "Welcome to the world";

var parts = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(str, " ");
Array.Reverse(parts);

var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var part in parts)
{
    sb.Append(part);
    sb.Append(' ');
}

if (sb.Length > 0)
{
    sb.Length--;
}

var str2 = sb.ToString();
```

Note that `Regex`(es) aren't part of the `System.String` class :-) :-) (they are `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`)

Comment: I guess the OP's **excercise/challenge/homework** is to deal with the **string data structure** directly than using any other methods (he might not know that `Regex` could also do this).

Comment: @KingKing This then teaches that when you want to put up some rules, it's important to be sure what exactly the rules are :-)

Answer (score 1):

Futile but,

```
public string GetReversedWords(string source)
{
    var word = new StringBuilder(source.Length);
    var result = new StringBuilder(source.Length);
    var first = true;
    foreach (var c in source.Reverse())
    {
        if (c.IsWhiteSpace)
        {
            first = WriteReverseWord(result, word, first);
            word.Clear();
            continue;
        }

        word.Append(c);
    }

    WriteReverseWord(result, word, first);
    return result.ToString();
}

private static bool WriteReverseWord(
    StringBuilder output,
    StringBuilder word,
    bool first)
{
    if (word.Length == 0)
    {
        return first;
    }

    if (!first)
    {
        output.Append(' ');
    }

    for (var i = word.Length -1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        output.Append(word[i]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is reverse actually String.Reverse ?

Comment: @PaulZahra no, its `IEnumerable.Reverse()`, `string` happens to implement `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using LINQ pretty easily as below:

```
 string str = "Welcome to the world";
 string[] arr = str.Split(' ').Reverse().ToArray();
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ",arr)); //Prints "world the to welcome"
```

Comment: `without using string functions` :-) `Split`/`Join`

Answer (score 0):

[Reference-VeeQuest](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/520330/How-to-reverse-a-string-sentence-only-words-not-ch)

```
/**Reverse a Sentence without using C# inbuilt functions
 (except String.Length property, m not going to write code for this small functionality )*/
const char EMPTYCHAR = ' ';
const string EMPTYSTRING = " ";

/// <summary>
/// Reverse a string Sentence
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pStr"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public string ReverseString(string pStr)
{
  if (pStr.Length > 1) //can be checked/restricted via validation
  {
    string strReversed = String.Empty;
    string[] strSplitted = new String[pStr.Length];
    int i;

    strSplitted = Split(pStr); // Complexity till here O(n)

    for (i = strSplitted.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    // this for loop add O(length of string) in O(n) which is similar to O(n)
    {
        strReversed += strSplitted[i];
    }

    return strReversed;
  }
  return pStr;
}

/// <summary>
/// Split the string into words & empty spaces
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public string[] Split(string str)
{
    string strTemp = string.Empty;
    string[] strArryWithValues = new String[str.Length];
    int j = 0;
    int countSpace = 0;

    //Complexity of for conditions result to O(n)
    foreach (char ch in str)
    {
        if (!ch.Equals(EMPTYCHAR))
        {
            strTemp += ch; //append characters to strTemp

            if (countSpace > 0)
            {
                strArryWithValues[j] = ReturnSpace(countSpace); // Insert String with Spaces
                j++;
                countSpace = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            countSpace++;

            if (countSpace == 1)
            {
                strArryWithValues[j] = strTemp; // Insert String with Words
                strTemp = String.Empty;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    strArryWithValues[j] = strTemp;
    return (strArryWithValues);
}

/// <summary>
/// Return a string with number of spaces(passed as argument)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="count"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public string ReturnSpace(int count)
{
    string strSpaces = String.Empty;

    while (count > 0)
    {
        strSpaces += EMPTYSTRING;
        count--;
    }

    return strSpaces;

}

/************Reverse Sentence Ends***************/
```